# firefox causes visual artifact with "transform:rotate;"

Tags: css, firefox, css-transforms, z-axis

Firefox is creating small lines on the triangles I've created and rotated.

[Chrome](https://memefly.me/i/a970f771336ec5a891feef70a09276b6.jpg)

[FireFox](https://memefly.me/i/86e9781d4a5b1d005a8ed286f1792956.jpg)

I've looked into what other questions have done and they recommended trying adding `transform: translateZ(1px) rotate(-45deg);` and `background-clip: padding-box;` but neither of those worked for me.

Also, it is only the rotated triangles that have the line in the firefox browser.

The page can be viewed at bingo-caller.herokuapp.com

Comment: share your code here

Comment: We can't test a solution without the code, but all the glitches related to rotation on Firefox that I see, mention as a solution to use " outline: 1px solid transparent;"

Comment: The page can be viewed at bingo-caller.herokuapp.com

Comment: @Daniel Didn't work for me.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: mcve]

Answer (score 1):

try this hack on the masked element: filter: blur(0.01px);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33217330)

Answer (score 0):

I tried on your page and it seems to work, add `translateZ(1px)` to the transform for the triangles.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, in this case the image is not to show code but to show the visual glitch mentioned in the issue getting fixed, I'm also mentioning the code that needs to be changed as text.

Answer (score 0):

Until now desc 2022 that still haven

I fix using border with color depending to the background and can not use transparent of border color e.g I use white because my parent background is white

```
border: 1px solid white;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).